# Adobe Air Mac App Store Receipt Validation

Tags: air, mac-app-store

We have an Adobe Air based app that we have successfully deployed for Mac but would like to bring to the Mac App Store. Following the instructions here http://pigsels.com/2012/04/air-app-store-publishing-guide/ and the Adobe forum thread mentioned on that page for the sandboxing part; we appeared to have a build capable of being deployed on the store.

What has since become a problem though is implementing the stores receipt DRM for our air app. The mac store places a receipt file inside the .app package when it is downloaded and this can be verified by following the instructions that Apple provides here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/ValidateA ppStoreReceipt/_index.html.

However seeing as we didn't have the ability to get the system GUID from within the Air player I created a separate executable to verify the receipt, the main Air app then calls that as a native process and validates. This was working great until the receipt checking executable was sandboxed as required by the Mac Store and can no longer access the receipt file.

What is the correct way to do receipt validation for an Air app on the mac store?